# Lyrics model design for django app

Tags: django, model

I am trying to create a lyrics app in Django. And I have come up with this model. The site will be community based, that is people will submit lyrics once they input the proper captcha challenge etc.. That comes at a price I guess, for example how can I enforce the relationship between `Song` and `Album`?

But most importantly is my design sound? Is there a need for more models?

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = False, blank = True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = True, blank = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = True, blank = True)
    biography = models.TextField(null=True, blank = True)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank = True)
    thumb = models.BinaryField(null=True, blank = True)
    num_stars = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank = True)

class Lyrics(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lyrics_content = models.TextField(null = False, blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    num_stars = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank = True)
    song_language = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = True, blank=True)    

class Song(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField(null = True, blank=True)
    num_stars = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    song_file = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

 class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField(null = True, blank=True)
    num_stars = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance, most things look OK.

In terms of the relationship between Song and Album, I would expect 1 song to be able to appear on more than one Album, so maybe a M2M relation there?

Also, songs could be performed by many Artists (original + several covers), so that relationship could probably be worked on in terms of flexibility, unless you want to treat a cover as a unique song - but then you get repetition of Lyrics, right?

Finally, I'm guessing the `thumb` field is to hold an image, so maybe that could be an `ImageField`?

Comment: Yea. That is one of the things that I am contemplating. My interest is actually in putting the lyrics out there and not on the songs although I may try to bundle these two together at a latter stage. But I am worried that my initial design might make improving the site difficult once deployed.

Comment: Yeah, I would say go for a highly normalized design first, and then see if you need to de-normalize later: no going back if you're missing relationships from the start, basically...